# Programming arduino using avrdude from command prompt

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, uploading, avrdude

Out of curiosity, I am trying to upload a simple hex file to Arduino UNO using avrdude from windows command prompt.

As per [this forum](https://asensar.com/blog/2013/programming-arduino-using-avrdude/), I tried to implement it. But got stuck at

> avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "COM41": The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

This command was directly imported from Arduino IDE verbose, and also it works fine when uploaded with Arduino IDE. I checked both the device and syntax are correct unless I would not be able to generate the hex file by Arduino compiler.

P.S. I have installed Winavr separately although it was pre-installed by Arduino
itself.

Here is a snapshot of the error [image: command prompt]

What could be the possible reason for it to fail? Please notify, if anything is missing.

Comment: I seems like you are using a different avrdude, as normally arduino uses the avrdude binary that is inside the arduino application folder. Also the avrdude conf-file is missing. So it looks to me like you have modified the command "directly imported" from the IDE.

Comment: @Gerben I downloaded the software Winavr and installed it separately. This is not the avrdude that was present inside arduino application folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of experiment, I finally made it. I got to know from some forum that when COM PORT is greater than 10, you have to put a '.' after COM PORT setting e.g. -P.COM41.

But, unfortunately that did not work. Then I changed the COM PORT to under 10 in device manager -> Properties -> COM Port Setting -> Advanced Setting; e.g. COM6.
Then it worked. At the time of flash just I have to press the RST button for once.
And now bingo!!

Still, I will try to find out why it didn't work with higher COM Port.

Answer (score 1):

```
can't open device "COM41": The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This means there is no device at `COM41`. This may be due to 2 reasons:

1. You may not have connected your arduino. If this is the case then you please connect the arduino and retry
2. Your arduino might be on a different COM port. If this is the case, then, go to device manager and check your arduino's COM port and replace `COM41` with that and retry.

Comment: No, that is not the case here. As I said I have connected the Arduino and in the device manager it showed COM41. And I can easily program it from arduino IDE, but when I try to upload using Avrdude it shows this particular error.